# How to apply marginLeft to a styledcomponent based on condition using react?

Tags: reactjs

i have a reusable component AddButton that uses IconButton component. AddButton when has active prop true and marginLeft prop then should apply marginLeft 14px if not 8px.

AddButton is used in Child1 and Child2 components. Child1 component passes marginLeft prop to the AddButton component.

below is my code,

```
function Child1() {
    return (
        <AddButton marginLeft={14}/> //here marginLeft prop passed
    );
}

 function Child2() {
    return (
        <AddButton /> 
    );
}

interface AddButtonProps {
    marginLeft?: number;
}

export const AddButton = ({marginLeft}: AddButtonProps) => {
    const [saving, setSaving] = React.useState(false);
    const {isDrawing} = useDrawing(item);

    return (
        <PrimaryButton active={isDrawing} marginLeft={marginLeft}/>
    );
};

interface PrimaryButtonProps {
    active?: boolean;
    marginLeft?: number;
}

const PrimaryButton = (props: PrimaryButtonProps) => {
    return <PrimaryIconButtonElement {...props} size={16} variant="primary" />;
};

const PrimaryIconButtonElement = styled(IconButton)<{
    $marginLeft?: number;
    $active?: boolean;
}>`
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-left: ${props =>
        props.$active && props.$marginLeft ? props.$marginLeft + 'px' : '8px'}; //this doesn't work
`;


function IconButton({active,size,...rest}: Props) {
    return (
        <Wrapper $active={active}>
            <Icon size={size}/>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

now when the active prop is true and marginLeft is passed for AddButton component, then i want the PrimaryButtonElement to have marginLeft 14px.

but for some reason this style doesnt get applied with the above code.

Could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: Are you using the styledcomponents package?

Comment: yes using it...

Comment: Maybe because you are consuming the "active" property in the "IconButton" it is not being passed down to the styledcomponent. remove the property in the "IconButton" or log to see if the property is really being received at the styledcomponent

Answer (score 0):

According to the styled-component documentation:

The styled method works perfectly on all of your own or any third-party components, as long as they attach the passed className prop to a DOM element.

https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component

So, in your case you need to:

Add to your Props interface a className field:

```js
interface Props {
  active?: boolean;
  size?: number;
  className?: string;
}
```

And on your IconButton, include className:

```js
function IconButton({active, size, className, ...rest}: Props) {
    return (
        <Wrapper className={className} active={active}>
            <Icon size={size}/>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

You also need to remove $ prefix of your props on PrimaryIconButtonElement:

```
const PrimaryIconButtonElement = styled(IconButton)<{
  marginLeft?: number;
  active?: boolean;
}>`
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-left: ${(props) =>
    props.active && props.marginLeft
      ? props.marginLeft + "px"
      : "8px"};
`;
```

I did a test replacing your Wrapper and Icon tags for a div and all worked well.

*If your wrapper is a react component, you will need to send className to it too.